# SharePoint 2010 Record Declaration Settings via Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have 200 site collections that need to perform the following tasks:-

A. At the Site Collection Administration - Record Declaration Settings

1. Set Record Restriction to **Block Delete**
2. Set Record Declaration Availability to **Available in all locations by default**
3. Set Declaration Roles - The declaration of records can be performed by: **All list contributors and administrators**
4. Set Declaration Roles - Undeclaring a record can be performed by - **Only list administrator**

B. At the Document Library Settings -  Record Declaration Settings

1. Set manual record declaration availability to **Always allow the manual declaration of records**

How can I do the above tasks via Powershell.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the full script for the above task

```
function Set-Feature([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite] $Site)
{
    $feature = Get-SPFeature InPlaceRecords
    Enable-SPFeature $feature -Url $Site.Url
}

function Set-Audit ([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite] $Site)
{
    $Site.Audit.AuditFlags=[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAuditMaskType]::None 
    $Site.Audit.Update()

    $auditMask = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAuditMaskType]::View -bxor
                 [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAuditMaskType]::Update -bxor
                 [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAuditMaskType]::CheckIn -bxor
                 [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAuditMaskType]::CheckOut -bxor
                 [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAuditMaskType]::Delete -bxor
                 [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAuditMaskType]::Undelete -bxor
                 [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAuditMaskType]::Copy -bxor
                 [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAuditMaskType]::Move -bxor
                 [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAuditMaskType]::SecurityChange 
    $Site.TrimAuditLog = $false
    $Site.Audit.AuditFlags = $auditMask
    $Site.Audit.Update()
}

function Set-ContentTypePublishingHub([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite] $Site)
{
    if($Site.RootWeb.Properties.ContainsKey("MetadataTimeStamp"))
    {
        $Site.RootWeb.Properties["MetadataTimeStamp"] = [string]::Empty
        $Site.RootWeb.Update()
    }
}

function Set-RecordDeclarationSetting([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite] $Site)
{
    if($Site.RootWeb.AllProperties.ContainsKey("ecm_siterecordrestrictions"))
    {
        $Site.RootWeb.AllProperties["ecm_siterecordrestrictions"] = "BlockDelete"
    }

   if($Site.RootWeb.AllProperties.ContainsKey("ecm_siterecorddeclarationdefault"))
   {
       $Site.RootWeb.AllProperties["ecm_siterecorddeclarationdefault"] = "True"
   }

if($Site.RootWeb.AllProperties.ContainsKey("ecm_siterecordundeclarationby"))
{
    $Site.RootWeb.AllProperties["ecm_siterecordundeclarationby"] = "OnlyAdmins"
}

if($Site.RootWeb.AllProperties.ContainsKey("ecm_siterecorddeclarationby"))
{
    $Site.RootWeb.AllProperties["ecm_siterecorddeclarationby"] = "AllListContributors"
}

$Site.RootWeb.Update()
}

function Set-SharedDocumentSettings([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb] $Web)
{
    $lib = $Web.Lists.TryGetList("Shared Documents")

if($lib -ne $null)
{
    $lib.EnableVersioning = $true
    $lib.EnableMinorVersions = $true
    $lib.EnableModeration = $false
    $lib.DraftVersionVisibility = "Reader"
    $lib.ForceCheckout = $true
    $lib.ContentTypesEnabled = $true

    $lib.Update()

    $lib.RootFolder.Properties["ecm_IPRListUseListSpecific"] = "True"
    $lib.RootFolder.Properties["ecm_AllowManualDeclaration"] = "True"
    $lib.RootFolder.Update()

    $documentCT = $lib.ContentTypes | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "Document"}
    $lib.ContentTypes.Delete($documentCT.Id)

    $ct1 = $Web.AvailableContentTypes | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "CTH-AU"}
    $ct2 = $Web.AvailableContentTypes | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "CTH-BU"}

    $lib.ContentTypes.Add($ct1)
    $lib.ContentTypes.Add($ct2)

    $lib.Update()


}

}

function Set-AllDocLibSettings([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb] $Web)
{
    foreach($lib in $web.Lists)
    {
        if($lib.BaseType -eq [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBaseType]::DocumentLibrary)
        {
            $lib.EnableVersioning = $true
            $lib.EnableMinorVersions = $true
            $lib.EnableModeration = $false
            $lib.DraftVersionVisibility = "Reader"
            $lib.ForceCheckout = $true
            $lib.ContentTypesEnabled = $true

            $lib.Update()

            $lib.RootFolder.Properties["ecm_IPRListUseListSpecific"] = "True"
            $lib.RootFolder.Properties["ecm_AllowManualDeclaration"] = "True"
            $lib.RootFolder.Update()

            $documentCT = $lib.ContentTypes | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "Document"}
            $lib.ContentTypes.Delete($documentCT.Id)

            $ct1 = $Web.AvailableContentTypes | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "CTH-AU"}
            $ct2 = $Web.AvailableContentTypes | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "CTH-BU"}

            $lib.ContentTypes.Add($ct1)
            $lib.ContentTypes.Add($ct2)

            $lib.Update()           
        }
}


}

$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication -Identity http://vmkulsp2:35384

foreach($Site in $webApp.Sites)
{
    #Common
    Set-Feature $Site
    Set-Audit $Site
    Set-ContentTypePublishingHub $Site
    Set-RecordDeclarationSetting $Site

$collaborateId = "112005"
$projectId = "112004"

foreach($web in $Site.AllWebs)
{
    $webTemplateId = $web.WebTemplateId.ToString()

    #Collobration Site
    if($webTemplateId -eq $collaborateId)
    {
        Set-SharedDocumentSettings $web
    }
    #project site
    elseif ($webTemplateId -eq $projectId)
    {
        Set-AllDocLibSettings $web
    }

    $web.Dispose()
}

$Site.Dispose()
}
```

Hope this helps the community
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is how "point Always allow the manual declaration of records" can be done:

```
    $web = get-spweb http://TestWeb
    $list = $web.Lists["ListName"]
    $list.RootFolder.Properties["ecm_IPRListUseListSpecific"] = "True"
    $list.RootFolder.Properties["ecm_AllowManualDeclaration"] = "True"
    $list.RootFolder.Update()
```

Comment: Use the following line of code to deselect the option "Automatically declare items as records when they are added to this list":                                     [Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.RecordsRepository.Records]::ConfigureListFor‌​AutoDeclaration($list, $false);